# VB.net upload string to ftp server, to be saved as file

Tags: vb.net, ftp

Trying to upload a string content directly from vb.net app to a server using username and password, to be saved in the server as file. instead of uploading a file, possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**NEW ANSWER:**
Okay so there are two ways you can do this. The first is to create a temp file -containing your string- and write it to the FTP Server and delete the temp file after it has been written to the server. The second way is to use this online example I found: http://www.example-code.com/vb/ftp_uploadFromString.asp All you would have to do is replace the fileContents variable with your string. The only problem is that the Visual Basic Framework used is a 30-day trial so you would need to buy it.

**OLD ANSWER:**

> You need provide more information but I'm going to try and understand
>   this. What you can is write the strings to your FTP Server. This is
>   pretty easy and you can easily find an example on google but here's a
>   link that will teach you how to setup your own FTP Client:
>
> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11991/An-FTP-client-library-for-NET-2-0
>
> Or you can use this which provides the downloadable source code only:
>
> http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=4655

Comment: i could upload files from my local drive to ftp server, using Network.UploadFile
what i am trying to do, is to set a string and upload it directly to the server as text file?